# Why does Cocoapods adds HockeyMac-SDK to my iOS Target?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoapods

Given that `Podfile`

```
workspace 'Foo'

target :Foo_Mac do
    xcodeproj 'Mac/Foo_Mac'
    platform :osx
    pod 'HockeySDK-Mac'
end

target :Foo_iOS do
    xcodeproj 'Foo_iOS'
    platform :ios, '7.0'
    pod 'Parse-iOS-SDK'
end
```

How comes both my `Pods-Foo_iOS.xcconfig` & `Pods-Foo_Mac.xcconfig` contains

```
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/HockeySDK-Mac" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Parse-iOS-SDK"
```

Shouldn't it just have the ones from the `Podfile`?

Answer (score 1):

You’re absolutely right, that’s a bug. Please [file a ticket](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues).

Comment: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1619 which apparently is https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/1590 ;)